# Qt6 widget->showMaximized freezes on first show

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

After upgrading to qt version 6.2 from qt5 I faced the problem with starting the app in the maximized mode. The widget is first painted with it's normal size and then repainted fine. The intermediate state is shown on the gif below:
[image: Invalid QWidget::paintEvent on first show]

The code of the app from the giff comes together with Qt (my version is Qt-6.2.3) and called "styles" (path is Qt/Examples/Qt-6.2.3/widgets/widgets/styles) or can be found on the [qt.io](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/widgets/styles?h=6.2.3). I have just changed `widget.show()` to `widget.showMaximized()` in main.cpp.

I figured out that sometimes widget starts fine, but this is rather rare. Also the more complicated widget is, the more time it takes to correctly paint it on the first show.
In the example from the gif the start is so quick that it is almost invisible, but in the heavy app I'm working with this slow startup really catches the eye.

If this can not be easy fixed, does anybody have any idea how to mask this behaviour? I thought about painting the widget on the virtual framebuffer and moving it back to the main display right after first show, but I did not find any easy means to create it in c++.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I finally reported a bug to qt developers.
See [QTBUG-104357](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-104357)

Comment: You should show the implementation of `MainWindow`, otherwise we can hardly help you. If it freezes, then you should also build it in debug mode and run with debugger attached. Once it freezes, then just interrupt the execution and see where the application code got stuck.

Comment: I have just found out that it seems to be internal qt's default behavior and this is  repeated in the qt's examples. I have edited my question, so that it now not related to any user code.

Comment: I can see the problem now. I though that the application actually freezes as the title suggests. The original question was not clear to me. And yes, this is really how Qt behaves in some versions, at least on Windows. First it resizes the window, fills it with white color and then paints the content. If the content takes time to paint, then the white areas are visible for a moment. I am however surprised that this is still an issue in Qt 6.2. I have reported similar issue https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89688 and it was claimed to be fixed. I think you should create another bug report.